# Understanding the proof that the ring of regular rational functions at $P$, $\mathcal{O}_P$, is an evaluation ring.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, algebraic-curves, valuation-theory

**Definitions:**

Given $V(I=\{F\})=\mathbf{\mathcal{X}}_F\subset \mathbb{P}^{2}(K)$ a smooth projective curve, and $P$ a point of the curve, $\mathcal{O}_P$ is the ring of rational funcions that are regular at $P$. If $Q_F$ is the field of fractions of $K[X,Y,Z]/V(F)$ I have this definition:
$$\mathcal{O}_P:=\Big{\{}\;\frac{G}{H}\;\;\Big{|}\;\; (\frac{G}{H}\in Q_F)\;\land\;(G\;\text{y}\;H\;\text{homogeneus})\;\land\;(deg(G)=deg(H))\land\;(G(P)\neq 0)\Big{\}}$$

**The claim:**

The maximal ideal $\mathcal{M}_P=\{f\in\mathcal{O}_P\;|\; f(P)=0\}$ of  $\mathcal{O}_P$ is a principal ideal.

**The proof I don't fully understand**

So this is the proof of book I am reading:

"We want to show that the maximal ideal $\mathcal{M}_{P}$ is a principal ideal, that is to
say, generated by one element. Let $\mathbf{\mathcal{X}}$ be a smooth curve in $\mathbb{A}^{2}$ defined by the equation $F=0$, and let $P = (a, b)$ be a point on $\mathbf{\mathcal{X}}$. The maximal ideal $\mathcal{M}_P$ is
generated by $(x-a)$ and $(y-b)$. Now
$$F_{X}(P)(x - a) + F_Y (P)(y - b) \equiv 0\pmod {\mathcal{M}_P^2}$$

Hence the K-vector space $\mathcal{M}_P/\mathcal{M}_P^2$ has dimension 1, and therefore $\mathcal{M}_P$ has one generator."

I don't understand how the tangent being  $0\pmod {\mathcal{M}_P^2}$ implies that $\mathcal{M}_P/\mathcal{M}_P^2$ has dimension 1, and how that translates to $\mathcal{M}_P$ having 1 generator.

Comment: The second part follows from Nakayama (ie if $(A,m)$ is a local ring – here $A=\mathcal{O}_P$ – and $M$ is a finitely generated $A$-module – here $M=\mathcal{M}_P$ – and $x_1, \ldots,x_r$ generate $M/mM$, then $x_1,\ldots,x_r$ generate $M$). Indeed, if $N$ is the $A$-module generated by $x_1,\ldots,x_r$, $M/N$ is finitely generated and $m(M/N)=(M/N)$ so $M/N=0$ ie $M=N$. For the first part, the equality mod $\mathcal{M}_P^2$ show that $x-a,y-b$ (the generators of $\mathcal{M}_P /\mathcal{M}_P^2$) aren’t a free family, so that vector space has dimension at most $1$.

Comment: @Mindlack, thank you for your answer. I wuold upvote if i could

Comment: The curve needs to be smooth at $P$, for example $X^2Z- Y^3$ isn't smooth at $P=[0:0:1]$, the local ring is $O_P\cong (K[t^2,t^3]-(t^2,t^3))^{-1}K[t^2,t^3]$, the maximal ideal is $(t^2,t^3)$, non principal

Comment: @reuns, yes I forgot to say that the curve is smooth. I will add that, thatk you.